# spark 2.4.4 shuffle data seems to be not cleaned up

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, shuffle

I have a question regarding to spark shuffle data. I'm using spark 2.4.4 and monitor my spark disk usage. I notice the disk space is never freed for some reason. I cached my data and unpersist the dataframe which I don't need (based on: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/277/how-do-i-avoid-the-no-space-left-on-device-error.html). But it didn't help.

My question is, if I have following code

```
# step1: load data

df_a = spark.read.csv(PAHT_TO_A, schema=schema).repartition('uid').select('uid', 'value').cache()

# step2: aggregate the data

df_b = df_a.select('uid', 'value').reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).toDF(['uid', 'aggregated_values']).repartition('uid').cache()

print('size of df_b: %d' % df_b.count())

# step3: remove dataframe a

df_a.unpersist()

# step4 .....
```

My understanding is, the shuffle data created in step2 should be removed by gc after step3. I should see the
disk space be freed up.

However, in my application, I need to do many aggregation on different datasets. As a result, my disk space keeps decreasing until I got disk space error message in later steps.

The only thing works for me is to put step1, step2 and step3 into single application and save df_b back to s3. Once this application
is finished, the disk space is freed up. I then create another application to load df_b again.

Is there any problem about this code? Or there is anything I can optimize?

Thanks a lot

Update 1

Ok, my bad. Looks like I got confused. I believe I need to do

```
df_b.unpersist()
```

to remove the shuffle data

Comment: `upersist` -> `unpersist`

Comment: thx, that's a typo. Already fixed

Comment: Based on spark documentation, Note that this method does not block by default. To block until resources are freed, specify blocking=true when calling this method.

Comment: seems?  what can we do with that?